# Windows shared folder accessible only by Administrators

Tags: windows, permissions

Windows Server 2012 R2.

A shared folder was created and the permissions set to full control.

The share is only accessible by Administrators.

Why?

Answer (score 2):

When you set a shared folder in windows environment there are 2 permissions in action.

1 - Shared permission: This permission is set during shared folder config like picture bellow ...

[image]

2 - NTFS Permissions: This permission is set under properties -> security tab ...

[image]